# Is GAE request id globally unique?

Tags: google-app-engine

Is this `request_log_id` globally and forever unique for an individual application in Google App Engine?

```
String requestId = com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy.getCurrentEnvironment()
    .getAttributes().get("com.google.appengine.runtime.request_log_id");
```

We're considering using it to correlate user session info with the user's request in code called subsequent to the HttpServletRequest handler.